# Dagger Hilt having issues with AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, manifest, dagger

I recently added dagger to my Java android project and ever since I added the dependency, all the activities in the manifest start showing error stated as:
**"XYZActivity must extend android.app.Activity"** (instead of AppCompatActivity)

Whereas in the activity java files no methods (onCreate, for example) can be overridden anymore with the error:
**"Method does not override method from its superclass"**

Code for reference:

**Manifest:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.convo_z">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".utils.BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="DataExtractionRules"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        tools:targetApi="s">

        <activity android:name=".status.OwnStatusPage" />
        <activity android:name=".status.StatusPrivacyPage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".status.ViewStatusPage"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".settings.ProfileSettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".authentication.SignupActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".authentication.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".chat.ChatDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".verification.PhoneVerificationPage" />
        <activity android:name=".verification.OTPVerificationPage" />
        <activity android:name=".status.AddStatusPage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".splash.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build:gradle (app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\aryan\\.android\\debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.convo_z"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.5.1"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

**build:gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Hilt Application**

```
package com.example.convo_z.utils;

import android.app.Application;
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp;

@HiltAndroidApp
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
}
```

**HomeActivity.java**
(An activity where @Override now shows the above mentioned error)

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    Double pager = 0.0;

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.color.colorAccent));
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setElevation(0);

        Window window = HomeActivity.this.getWindow();
        // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        // finally change the color
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(HomeActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimaryVariant));
        //getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.drawable.core_colour2));
        //<gradient android:startColor="#333440" android:endColor="#333440"
        //  binding.viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i.hasExtra("pager"))
            pager = i.getDoubleExtra("pager", 0.0);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HomeActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                1);
    }
```

A help would be really appreciated :)

Extending Activity instead of AppCompatActivity solves the problem but isnt really a good solution.

Comment: did you try to clean the cache? You should be able to use `AppCompatActivity` with `Hilt` and `Dagger`

Comment: Yes I did. Invalidate Cache and Restart. Do you find any inconsistencies in the code though? I'm clearly new to dagger and hilt